# Android second layer on running camera app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I´m new in Android programming and I want to program a simple App for practise. I already searched the web for hours, but didn´t find any answers for my problem.

I want to put a 2. layer above the running camera app.

If I take a picture, it shouldn´t show the 2. Layer in the Picture, like there was never a 2. Layer.

That´s the current code, only working camera. A picture shows how it could look like:
http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=91520242013-08-03_19-25-33.png

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

        startCamera();

    }

    public void startCamera() {
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 0) {
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("date");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
            startCamera();
        }

    }


}
```

**Edit**

Logcat exception from answer:

```
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camerafront/com.example.camerafront.AndroidCamera}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.example.camerafront.AndroidCamera.onCreate(AndroidCamera.java:30)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  ... 11 more
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.camerafront-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.camerafront-2, /system/lib]]
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-04 12:33:44.403: E/AndroidRuntime(840):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: Take a look at: [How should I add elements to a custom camera android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932989/how-should-i-add-elements-to-a-custom-camera-android-application/17933418#17933418) and [Is it possible to add buttons to a framelayout that was set programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931151/is-it-possible-to-add-buttons-to-a-framelayout-that-was-set-programmatically/17931768#17931768)

Comment: try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799818/open-camera-using-intent/16815290#16815290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put a 2 overlay on the preview area, but you don't want the 2 to show up on the final image.

IF this is correct, I recommend taking a look at this post:
[Android: Overlay on Android Camera Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466336/android-overlay-on-android-camera-preview)

Basically this will tell you how to draw an overlay on top of the CameraView. Look at the example on the examples page (the one called CameraPreview). http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: So I tried to make this Tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2010/12/camera-preview-version-ii.html

I can´t start my App because of this error:
08-03 18:07:19.605: E/AndroidRuntime(893): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camerafront/com.example.camerafront.AndroidCamera}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class menu.

So what can I do now?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Try looking at this post to deal with the stack trace. This sounds like you're having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627566/error-didnt-find-class-android-view-menu-on-path

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help! i will try it tonight and tell about my result.

Comment: well, however i started the wrong main.xml :S ty for ur help! :)